# pillow imaging ImportError

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I installed Pillow 3.0.0 by pip onto my Python3.5 on my 32bit windows7 PC.
from PIL import Image
gives me:

```
File "C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 66, in <module>
    from PIL import _imaging as core
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

The Image file contains this comment:

```
# If the _imaging C module is not present, Pillow will not load.
```

The PIL directory contains no -imaging files. 
There was one called `_imaging.cp35-win32.pyc` but it has mysteriously disappeared after an overnight windows update.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Installation is broken. On Windows, the usual approach is uninstall/reinstall. Probably starting with just Pillow.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I reinstalled with pip and got the same result as before.  I believe there is another way to install using an egg...

Comment: I have tried again with:  easy_install pillow

Comment: I have tried again with:  easy_install pillow   and Í get "installed ......\pillow-3.0.0-py3.5-win32.egg" ...   "finished processing dependencies for pillow". There is now "no module named PIL". Am I supposed to process this egg to complete the installation?   What a marvellous resource this website is!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, after many times uninstalling/installing Pillow,I uninstalled my anaconda as i realized this Pillow package was not working properly . I reinstalled anaconda. And then it worked !

I don't know it is the best approach or not, but my problem was solved.