# Having installed Pillow in Anaconda3, Python 3 does not find it

Tags: python-3.x, import, anaconda, python-imaging-library

I have installed Pillow but when I try to import the Image module I get an exception:

[image]

[image]

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should try it like this: 
`from PIL import Image`

please refer [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/handbook/tutorial.html) for more clarity

Comment: @ Aneesh Damodaran:  Thank you.  I tried it but I get an exception:  from PIL import Image:  ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: after reading through few posts, it looks like architecture mismatch. [Got this from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43267754/importing-pil-more-specifically-image-from-pil-isnt-working): please try it once.
1. Uninstall it via `conda remove --force pillow`
2. Reinstall. Fearing something was wrong with the original Anaconda distribution: `conda install -c conda-forge pillow`

Comment: It worked!  I really appreciate your altrouism and time.  Congratulations!

Comment: Happy to know it helped you.